# Where is the CPanel Silex WebServer configuration file

Tags: configuration, webserver, cpanel, configuration-files, silex

I want to run my site's code in the local environment. The problem is, my local Silex doesn't work just like in the CPanel server.

Where is the CPanel Silex WebServer configuration file located? I want to view it and make my local Silex configuration the same with it.

UPDATE:

What I mean with WebServer configuration is based on this link:
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/web_servers.html

For Silex to work, for example, if we use Apache, we need to configure the web server by using `htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, what are you referring to when you are talking to "CPanel Silex WebServer configuration"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer on my own.

In `public_html` folder, you need to find `.htaccess` file. If you can't see it, set the File Manager to show hidden files from settings. Copy that `.htaccess` to your local environment and that's it.